# Kotlin: Getting "Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function'" error when try to add onReceivedError on a WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, overriding

I'm getting this error when I tried to handle errors on webView "Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function'"

If I remove the word 'Override' here, the app runs but the webView doesn't handle the errors, if I add the word 'override' the app doesn't run

```
override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest, error: WebResourceError) {
webView.loadUrl("about:blank")                
Toast.makeText(this, "Favor de conectarse a la red de EJ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

This is my whole code, the goal is show a message and load a blank page if the webView doesn't load the target page

```
package com.example.myApp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.webkit.*
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val BASE_URL = "http://myPage/instruccion/"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {

        }

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

        }

        val settings :WebSettings = webView.settings
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        settings.builtInZoomControls = true
        settings.setSupportZoom(true)
        webView.loadUrl(BASE_URL)
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)

        override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest, error: WebResourceError) {
            webView.loadUrl("about:blank")                
            Toast.makeText(this, "Favor de conectarse a la red de EJ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did some changes and now works, this was the solution:

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

            override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest, error: WebResourceError) {
                webView.loadUrl("about:blank")                
                Toast.makeText(this, "Favor de conectarse a la red de EJ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

    }
```